# Galaxy S4 - Exchange ActiveSync picks wrong Display Name

Tags: exchange, active-sync

When I add an MSN @live.com email account the Galaxy S4, it doesn't pick the Display Name set by Exchange.

From the web interface, it shows the Display Name set as the full name (e.g. John Smith), but on Android, all out-going emails have the username set as the Display Name (e.g. jsmith).

The Display Name for office365.com email accounts seems to be working fine, but not for @live.com email accounts.

Further more, Android doesn't give the option to re-set or update the Display Name in Exchange ActiveSync email accounts. That options is available under IMAP and POP3 email accounts only.

Is this a new issue?

Has anyone been able to fix this?

I called Samsung and they couldn't find a solution in their support knowledge base, asked me to contact my Cellphone Carrier. I called my Callphone Carrier and they said it's out-of-scope for their Support and that I should contact Samsung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake, I'd like to point out that after doing research online, I have found out that this is an issue plaguing Samsung Galaxy S2 and S3 as well. Most of the discussions on this issue end with, "Why don't you just get a @gmail account?"

Since I refuse to have an email with numbers in it, I am going to stick to my more professional looking email on @live.com. I don't want to put an ugly email like jsmith223@live.com on my resume or any other correspondence for that matter.

Anyhoo, long story short, if you have a hotmail email address (@hotmail.com, @live.com, @outlook.com, etc) and you value a synchronized mailbox (meaning, having all sent and read messages marked as such on your desktop, web mailbox and phone regardless of where you sent or read a message), then don't get an Android device until there is concrete evidence online of someone being able to show that it works. POP3 is archaic technology from the mid-90s. IMAP isn't a whole lot newer, but you can still get by with IMAP. Unfortunately, Microsoft has refused to offer IMAP services on hotmail accounts. So your only options are POP3 and Exchange ActiveSync (EAS).

Answer (score 0):

Can I just point out that this isn't an android issue but a Samsung issue. The android stock email app on a vanilla Rom allows you to set the "Your Name" field. Samsung's modified email app doesn't have this field